# What is the relationship between "Hammer Works" and this "Astrud Gilberto With Stan Getz - Girl From Ipanema (1964)" video?

Tags: music-video, music-business, production

At the end of the YouTube video [Astrud Gilberto With Stan Getz - Girl From Ipanema (1964)](https://youtu.be/_1uEy-n4IsU) there is a few seconds showing an animated logo with the words "Hammer Works".

Is that a video production company, a record label, something else? What is it and how does it connect to the video?

[image: "Astrud Gilberto With Stan Getz - Girl From Ipanema (1964)" https://youtu.be/_1uEy-n4IsU]

I've found two similar images potentially related to music production, but I don't think these help:

[image: https://www.discogs.com/master/823279-Graham-Fellows-Men-Of-Oats-And-Creosote] [image: https://www.discogs.com/release/17533396-The-Grimethorpe-Colliery-Band-Brass-Band-Classics]

Image sources:

1. https://www.discogs.com/master/823279-Graham-Fellows-Men-Of-Oats-And-Creosote
2. https://www.discogs.com/release/17533396-The-Grimethorpe-Colliery-Band-Brass-Band-Classics